# How does server verify the identity of a client (without client certificate) in a HTTPS communication?

Tags: ssl, https

In a TLS handshake, the server can verify the identity of the client by verifying the client certificate.

How is the identity verified in the case of TLS communication without a client certificate?

Comment: BTW, TLS is always two ways, you can not have one path using TLS and the other doing something else, it is full duplex.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: it's not verified.

Without a client certificate, the identity of the client isn't verified by the TLS protocol.

Non-TLS based means can be used to verify the client identity (e.g. a logon with a password), but without a client certificate, it isn't done via TLS.